# How do I get values from a nested list in R when the sublists are different sizes and not named?

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a list of n lists, each of which are different lengths. These lists contain a third level list of two character vectors, one which is the name of the value and the other is the value. I want to extract all the values where the same name is present in all the lists. Here's some fake data to illustrate the problem.

```
dput(list(list(list(c("name", "Date"), c("value", "2012-08-17")), 
    list(c("name", "Time"), c("value", "23:12:07 -0800 (PST)"
    )), list(c("name", "Condition"), c("value", "smooth"))), 
    list(list(c("name", "Date"), c("value", "2012-09-23")), list(
        c("name", "ID"), c("value", "23")), list(c("name", "Time"
    ), c("value", "21:56:42 -0800 (PST)")), list(c("name", "Condition"
    ), c("value", "smooth"))), list(list(c("name", "Date"), c("value", 
    "2012-07-01")), list(c("name", "Time"), c("value", "06:05:17 -0800 (PST)"
    )), list(c("name", "Condition"), c("value", "smooth"))), 
    list(list(c("name", "Date"), c("value", "2012-06-07")), list(
        c("name", "ID"), c("value", "23")), list(c("name", "Time"
    ), c("value", "14:07:56 -0800 (PST)")), list(c("name", "Property"
    ), c("value", "hard")), list(c("name", "Condition"), c("value", 
    "smooth")))))
```

You can see that the lists have different lengths and the order of the values are different, so I can't just do `value<-data[[i]][[j]]` because when I increment i, j comes back as different values. `data[[1]][[3]]` would give the `Condition` list, whereas `data[[2]][[3]]` would give the `Time` list.

They're not named, so I can't do `["name"]` to get the value.

I've tried things like `values<-sapply(data, function(x) sapply(x, "[[", 2))` but this just gives me a character vectors with all the values from the lists, which isn't so helpful.

Seems like since at the lowest level I have a set of key-value pairs, I should be able to pull this into a dataframe of some sort where the columns are the names present in all lists (Date, Time, Condition) and the rows are the values corresponding to the names as you iterate through the lists.

I am thinking about some horrible for loop involving grep, but is there a better way?

Comment: How did you wind up with such an ugly list? You might take a step or two back to see if there's a better way to build the data in the first place.

Comment: This is how the gmailr package returns data. I'm thinking of trying something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend respahing the list to something more sane. Here's one such transformation.

```
newdata <- lapply(
    lapply(data, function(x) 
        lapply(x, function(y) 
            setNames(sapply(y,"[",2), sapply(y,"[",1))
        )
    ), function(x) 
        setNames(sapply(x,"[","value"),sapply(x,"[","name"))
)
```

this will return

```
[[1]]
                  Date                   Time              Condition 
          "2012-08-17" "23:12:07 -0800 (PST)"               "smooth" 

[[2]]
                  Date                     ID                   Time              Condition 
          "2012-09-23"                   "23" "21:56:42 -0800 (PST)"               "smooth" 

[[3]]
                  Date                   Time              Condition 
          "2012-07-01" "06:05:17 -0800 (PST)"               "smooth" 

[[4]]
                  Date                     ID                   Time               Property              Condition 
          "2012-06-07"                   "23" "14:07:56 -0800 (PST)"                 "hard"               "smooth"
```

If you want to go the extra step and turn this into a data.frame, you can use `dplyr` to help

```
library(dplyr)
rbind_all(lapply(newdata, function(x) data.frame(as.list(x), stringsAsFactors=F)))
```

which will give

```
        Date                 Time Condition ID Property
1 2012-08-17 23:12:07 -0800 (PST)    smooth NA       NA
2 2012-09-23 21:56:42 -0800 (PST)    smooth 23       NA
3 2012-07-01 06:05:17 -0800 (PST)    smooth NA       NA
4 2012-06-07 14:07:56 -0800 (PST)    smooth 23     hard
```

Comment: Nice solution, and fast!